# type JavaConversions is not applicable for the arguments (Set<String>)

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

Here is the code snippet :

```
protected static List<String>  myclass(String mydata){

     scala.collection.Set<String> abc = <**some code that returns set of strings**(scala code)>

      List<String> 123 = JavaConversions.<?>(abc)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can convert Set to Seq then code can compiled as,

```
protected static List<String>  myclass(String mydata){

     scala.collection.Set<String> abc = <**some code that returns set of strings**(scala code)>

      List<String> 123 = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(abc.toSeq)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be due to the type you are using: `scala.collection.Set` instead of `scala.collection.immutable.Set`. Any particular reason for using the interface instead of the immutable version? https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.0/scala/collection/Set.html

this worked for me:

```
scala> import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

scala> val s = Set("abc","def")
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(abc, def)

scala> s.asJava
       ^
       warning: object JavaConverters in package collection is deprecated (since 2.13.0): Use `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters` instead
res4: java.util.Set[String] = [abc, def]
```

or as recommended by the warning:

```
scala> import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

scala> val s = Set.of("abc", "def")
                   ^
       error: value of is not a member of object scala.collection.immutable.Set

scala> val s = Set("abc", "def")
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(abc, def)

scala> s.asJava
asJava   asJavaCollection

scala> s.asJava
res1: java.util.Set[String] = [abc, def]

scala> s.asJavaCollection
res3: java.util.Collection[String] = [abc, def]
```